# WinCE Image for MIPS

Tags: image, windows-ce, mips

Does anyone have image of Win CE (5.0 or 6.0) for MIPS processor?

I'm currently use Microsoft Device Emulator v 3.0
I have image for ARM processor, but my target device has MIPS.
Therefore it is impossible to perform some tests on PC.

To simplify task: I need an image to test application built for STANDARD SDK 5.0 MIPSII

Answer (score 2):

It's not that simple. This isn't a desktop OS where peripherals use a common set of busses and addresses and a single OS build that knows how to integrate all of these.  There isn't a "Windows CE Image" for just any given processor, the OS image must be built for your exact hardware.  Memory maps, peripherals, drivers and a load of other things can change from board to board, even with the same processor.

These "differences" are encapsulated in what's known as a BSP or board support package.  You generally must have that for your target hardware, then you can generate a new OS image containing the OS features you want for that hardware.

The short of this is that no one can tell you if they have a compatible OS image without knowing the exact hardware you have.  Even with that information, it's highly unlikely anyone other than the device OEM would have an image for it.

**EDIT**

You note that you need this for the Device Emulator.  The Device Emulator is, for all intents, an ARM device, so it can't run a MIPS OS at all.  If you want to test your application against the emulator, you need to compile it against an ARM SDK.

Comment: I've changed little bit my question. Added processor specification.

Comment: That is what i'm doing now - compiling it with ARM SDK. But I have some MIPS libraries which I would like to test... This is the final goal

Comment: Without MIPS hardware you can't test them and the Emulator is not MIPS.  You need actual, physical hardware with a CE OS provided by the OEM.

Comment: Thanks, MS Device Emulator really is working for ARM-images. I was thinking that it is possible to use it for MIPS-images also or some other special tool exists.